isKeyPressed() function is not working for me
I am trying to write a script that executes a mouse movement when the character "f" on the keyboard is pressed but for some reason it doesn't work. Any suggestions?
function test(event,arg)
    if isKeyPressed("f") then
        repeat
            MoveMouseRelative(0,20)
        until not isKeyPressed("f")
    end
end


It is impossible.
GHub is unable to see if a keyboard key is down or up.  Only some keys could be monitored (Shift/Alt/Ctrl), you can also monitor LEDs (NumLock/ScrollLock/CapsLock). On a Logitech keyboard special G-keys (G1, G2, ...) are also monitorable, they generate events similar to events of mouse buttons.
Use some mouse button instead of F
